# boost: checked_delete.hpp references non-existent core directory

Tags: boost

I am building some software that depends on boost. The build failed with the error:
`/usr/include/boost/checked_delete.hpp:15:41: fatal error: boost/core/checked_delete.hpp: No such file or directory`

The checked_delete.hpp file in /usr/include/boost/ says that it is deprecated, and refers to the same file in a subdirectory, boost/core/checked_delete.hpp:

```
        /*
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Glen Fernandes
 *
 * Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See
 * accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
 * http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */

#ifndef BOOST_CHECKED_DELETE_HPP
#define BOOST_CHECKED_DELETE_HPP

**// The header file at this path is deprecated;
// use boost/core/checked_delete.hpp instead.**

#include <boost/core/checked_delete.hpp>

#endif
```

However, I can't find the core directory in usr/include/boost, which seems to be the cause of the error. I tried removing and then reinstalling boost (sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev), but the error persisted. I am using version 1.58.0.

Why would boost reference a core directory it doesn't have? Do I have to do something to boost to create this directory after installing?

Comment: I see `checked_delete.hpp`; it exists in version 1.66/1.67/1.68. Can you upgrade boost and try again?

Comment: If you are on an old ubuntu version, you may need to install boost from boost.org: https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.69.0/source/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that apt-get wouldn't provide the most recent option.  I installed boost 1.69.0 from the link you mentioned. Now I'm running into a separate issue, but this has fixed my immediate problem